# Response 'Bad request' in HTML-body from MS Exchange OWA

Tags: java, android, webview, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I create android app with WebView inside myActivity.

> public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState)
>       { 
>         super.onCreate( savedInstanceState);
>
> ```
>   // before setContentView
>   CookieSyncManager.createInstance( this);
>   CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
>   CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
>   CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie( true);
>
>   setContentView( R.layout.browser);
>
>       webviewHTML = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webviewHTML);
>       WebSettings webSettings = webviewHTML.getSettings();
>       webSettings.setSupportZoom( true);
>       webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls( true);
>       webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled( true);
>       webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically( true);
>       webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled( false);
>       webSettings.setSaveFormData( false);
>       webSettings.setSavePassword( false);
>       webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName( "utf-8");
>       webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled( true);
>       webSettings.setUserAgent( 0);
>       webviewHTML.setWebViewClient( new myWebViewClient());
>       webviewHTML.addJavascriptInterface( new myJavaScriptInterface(), getString( R.string.sAppName));
>       webviewHTML.setOnLongClickListener( onWebViewLongClickListener);
>
>       webviewHTML.loadUrl( "myaddress");
> }
> ```

When create WebView I open page of my corporate Microsoft Exchange 2010 OWA 'https://mail.mydomain.com/owa/':

[image]

Then I manual enter username and password from my domain.
But I get error message page inside WebView (response code 200):

> `<head><head></head><body>Bad Request</body></head>`

Screenshot:

[image]

But when I open this page inside any browser (Chrome) I correct enter to OWA mail page:
[image]

Why Exchange server return html-page with error inside body?

What I need add to WebView properties?

**Add:**
Also when I open this page in desktop browser on PC window for username and password popup inside browser (not site):

[image]

**Add solution** I find my error. I check URL in WebView.myWebViewClient.onPageFinish and URL was different with my starting URL. I correct this URL and my page will open correct.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
webSettings.setUserAgent( 0);
```

For

```
webSettings.setUserAgentString("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
```

Explanation: you are purposefully setting identifying yourself (the webview) as an inexistent browser, and Exchange probably doesn't like that. With this change, you will indentify yourself as Firefox.

**Answer extension**

Also, in order to get rid of that authentication request, you should use add to the webview your own class which extends `WebViewClient` and implements `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest()`.

For example:

```
    webviewHTML = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webviewHTML);

    (...)

    MPascualViewClient myNewClient = new MPascualViewClient();
    webviewHTML.setWebViewClient(myNewClient);

    (...)

    webviewHTML.loadUrl( "myaddress");
}

private class MPascualViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
    HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onReceivedHttpAuthRequest: " + host);
        String user = "a username"; //get this string from wherever you want
        String password = "a password"; //get this string from wherever you want

        handler.proceed(user, password);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this not work for me. Also I add new info about open this page in desktop browser on PC.

Comment: I added more code to answer you question's extension

Comment: I try implement this code, but not work for me. You forward me to another direction and I find my error. I check URL in WebView onPageFinish and URL different from my start URL. I correct this URL and my page will open correct. Thank you!

Comment: This fixed the same problem for me where I was using HttpGet to download attachments from Outlook Web Access, and OWA required both the Cookies and User-Agent header fields to be set.